# Fire event after searchbox user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, search-box

Ok so I want to fire a jquery event, after a user types in the search box.

**Search box:**

```
<div class="input-group">    
    <input type="search" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input searchField-active ui-autocomplete-loading" placeholder="Sök på Dustin" name="filter.query" accesskey="s" autocomplete="off" id="searchBox">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="search" name="search" id="searchTrigger" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="icon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

After a user types in the searchbox fire this **jQuery**:

```
$(".hidden").removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Demo [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/ekhT4/2347/) and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/5Assc/897/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onchange` or `onkeyup` events to call function

```
<input type="search" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input searchField-active ui-autocomplete-loading" placeholder="Sök på Dustin" onkeyup="RemoveClass()" name="filter.query" accesskey="s" autocomplete="off" id="searchBox">

<script>
    function RemoveClass() {
        $(".hidden").removeClass('hidden');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This below code perform operation whenever user gives input to the search box.

```
$("#searchBox).on({
   input :function () {

                 $(".hidden").removeClass('hidden');

           }
});
```